# AWS MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID not working as expected

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-rds

Using RDS MySQL 8.0.28, with the following table

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 locale CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 content LONGTEXT NOT NULL 
);
```

after inserting a couple of entries and using `mysqlsh`, the following query returns successfully:

```
SELECT content FROM temp WHERE id=(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

+----------------------+
| content              |
+----------------------+
| this is another test |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.0788 sec)
```

however, ran on a lambda, it returns nothing. Any idea why?

Is this the only alternative?

```
SELECT content FROM temp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: mbmc - A larger worry is in 2038 when you are busy, your application will quit working due to the use of TIMESTAMP datatype - use DATETIME instead and avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), it wont work that way and also that is only for the last entry for the database connection , not client/table specific. [see LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) Instead , you could use

```
SELECT content FROM temp WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) from temp);
```

Comment: any performance impact compared to this `SELECT content FROM temp ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`?

Comment: i've tested both versions on a table with auto increment id column around 8mil rows , maybe 0.005 - 0.010 sec diff

Comment: @ucin What is the worry about 0.005 - 0.010 difference? Life goes on.  A larger worry is in 2038 when you are busy your application will quit working due to the use of TIMESTAMP datatype - use DATETIME instead and avoid the problem.